# AtomicIncrement using CompareAndSwap

Tags: c++, c, concurrency

Not homework, studying for an exam.

**My best attempt at a problem statement**:

Assume a thread calls AtomicIncrement, passing a pointer to a shared integer variable. It is not specified whether or not another thread will modify this variable, but it is possible. This implementation of Compare and swap returns 1 on successful swap and 0 on failure (old != value)

```
void AtomicIncrement(int *value, int amount) { 
    do { int old = *value; } // save old value 
    while (CompareAndSwap(value, old, old + amount) == 0); 
}
```

**Question:**

I am not really understanding what's going on here.

Is the reason why the code does " int old = *value; " because another thread could change (*value) between the do {} and while condition check?

[My textbook (page 10)](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-bugs.pdf) says "repeatedly tries to update value to the new amount" but I don't see how *value could be anything other than the original value passed into AtomicIncrement() by a calling thread, I must be missing something. The confusion comes from the fact that CompareAndSwap should be an atomic instruction to begin with, so there is no chance for *value to be changed during the "call" to CompareAndSwap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the temporary variable or loop, you'd be running `CompareAndSwap(value, *value, *value + amount)`. This is not atomic. There's a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point#Sequence_points_in_C_and_C.2B.2B) between evaluating a function's arguments (with no determine sequencing between evaluating each argument) and the function call itself.

This function must load `*value` to pass as an argument to `CompareAndSwap`. It must also load `*value` for use in the expression `*value + account`, also to pass as an argument.

Problem 1. Between the time when this thread loads `*value` and when it calls `CompareAndSwap`, `*value` could have been changed by another thread. That's why the loop is necessary.

Problem 2. There is no guarantee that the compiler emits only a single load of `*value`. It would be legal for it to load `*value` once, and add `amount` to a copy of it locally, but it would also be legal for it to load `*value` twice, once for use in the second argument and one for use in the third. If that happens, it's possible that another thread could have changed `*value` in between those loads. That's why the temporary variable is used, although that still doesn't actually guarantee a single load without a [memory barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).

Comment: Thank you. Would it thus be true to say that even though CompareAndSwap is a primitive instruction, it still follows the sequence point (calling conventions?) of C++? Or is it that the values themselves must be loaded before "calling" the atomic instruction?

Comment: @rpg711 I'd say: the `CompareAndSwap` function performs some operation atomically, but the C expression `CompareAndSwap(...)` is not atomic. You should also see that its definition uses some compiler extension to provide a memory fence.

Comment: In the absence of obtuse compiler mischief, what trouble could be caused by the use of an "ordinary" read for the old value?  If the read gets split and the split value happens to match the value of the storage location when the CompareAndSwap is called, the stored value will be one greater than the value when CAS is called, which is what should happen.  In all other cases where the read is split, the CAS will fail and the loop will repeat.  If one isn't using a mischievous compiler, what problem cases could arise?